# How to set size of webview in WallpaperService?

Tags: android, canvas, webview, size, live-wallpaper

I'm trying to set webview as a live wallpaper, but I have a problem with sizing it.

In the Engine I create a webview with WallpaperService's Context:

```
public WallpaperEngine(Context context) {
    webView = new WebView(context);
    ...
}
```

And I draw it to wallpaper's canvas:

```
SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
Canvas canvas = null;
try {
    canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
    if (canvas != null) {
        webView.draw(canvas);
    }
} finally {
    if (canvas != null)
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
}
```

But the wallpaper will be white and javascript reports, that window's size is 0px.

How to set size of the WebView?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by using WindowManager, defining size in LayoutParams and changing WebView visibility to GONE.

```
webView = new WebView(context);
webView.setVisibility(webView.GONE);
webView.loadUrl("http://example.com/");

wm = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
 );
params.width = //width
params.height = //height

wm.addView(webView, params);
```

Comment: Hello! I just found this page because I'm trying to put a WebView in a WallpaperService. I'm new to Android development, so I'm having trouble figuring out what to do. I've used your example here and I'm getting `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@e1a9690 -- permission denied for window type 2002` when I preview the wallpaper. I know it's been awhile since you posted this but any suggestions would be most welcome!

Comment: Android has been changed after I posted the question and I don't remember what the version was. The error you got seems to be permission related so maybe searching for permissions of the method you are using could help.

Comment: Yes! Looks like TYPE_PHONE needs to become TYPE_WALLPAPER. That gets me past that error. Now the new error is `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?`. Since the WallpaperService is a service, not an activity, do I even have an activity to add the window to? Is it possible to add a window to a service? If not, can I add an activity to the service so I can add the window to that? BTW, I've posted the general question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54263346/android-use-webview-for-wallpaperservice

Comment: Or is there another way to set the size of the WebView without having to call addView? I've tried calling setLayoutParams on the WebView, but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Okay, I found the solution to sizing the WebView: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54540300/306351 Thanks again for getting me started on the right track!